# Base and derived objects held in vector of base class type get sliced

Tags: c++, vector, derived-class

So I've just learned basics of vector template and I'm trying to make a vector holding both, **objects of Base and objects of Derived** classess. But derived objects get sliced (only the **baseVariable** is printed although it should also print **DerivedVariable**. So i have two questions, first:
Is creating a new object with user input done correctly here? Can I make it better or shorter?

```
Base* ptr = new Base();
            cin >> *ptr;
            vec.push_back(unique_ptr<Base>(ptr));
```

Why does Derived object get sliced?

```
class Base
{
protected:
    string baseVariable_;
public:
    void display() {
        cout << "BaseVar: " << baseVariable_ << endl;
    }
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Base& obj);

};
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Base& obj)
{
    in >> obj.baseVariable_;
    return in;
}



class Derived :public Base
{
public: //public just for test
    string derivedVariable_;
    void display() {
        Base::display();
        cout << "DerivedVar: " << derivedVariable_ << endl;
    }
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Derived& obj);
};
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Derived& obj)
{
    in >> obj.baseVariable_>> obj.derivedVariable_;
    return in;
}
int main()
{
    unsigned int choice = 0;
    vector<unique_ptr<Base>>vec;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << endl << "1. Add object of base class" << endl;
        cout << endl << "2. Add object of derived class" << endl;
        cout << endl << "3. Display all added objects to vector";
        cout << endl << "Choose option: ";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            Base* ptr = new Base();
            cin >> *ptr;
            vec.push_back(unique_ptr<Base>(ptr));
            
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            Derived* ptr = new Derived();
            cin >> *ptr;
            vec.push_back(unique_ptr<Base>(ptr));
            //delete ptr; <- it can't be here.
            break;
        }
        case 3:
            cout << "Displaying...\n";
            for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
            {
                vec[i]->display();
            }
            cout << "---------------------\n";
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Derived` objects will get sliced on destruction of `vec` because the `Base` destructor isn't `virtual`

Comment: please read about [mcve]. Your code is missing the includes and more importantly example input, output and expected output. I took the risk to write an answer anyhow, but I have no way to make sure if it solves your problem, because I wasnt able to find meaningful input and I didnt know what is the wrong/correct output

Comment: It did help, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no slicing in your code. You forgot to declare `Base::display` as virtual, hence calling `display` on a `Base*` will call `Base::display`.

```
class Base
{
protected:
    string baseVariable_;
public:
    virtual void display() {
    // ^^----------------------------------------------- !!!
        cout << "BaseVar: " << baseVariable_ << endl;
    }
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Base& obj);
    virtual ~Base() {}
};
```

And for polymorphic types you need to add a virtual destructor too.

Comment: You are right in this particular code, adding virtual fixed the problem. I had virtual on display method in my main program but it didnt work either. I fixed the issue by just rewriting vector/object creation. Thanks!

Comment: @RektLeft see my comment on your question. Without `virtual` it cannot work the way you expect. There might be more wrong in your code

Comment: I know 'virtual' is a must have if I want to edit method for derived class but I just forgot about it.

Comment: @RektLeft yes, thats ok, but you should not accept this answer when it does not solve the issue. What do you mean by "rewriting vector/object creation"?

Comment: But it did fix the code above so it must be an accepted answer. I mean the code from the thread.
`What do you mean by "rewriting vector/object creation"?`
Literally just removed everything and started from scratch.